# MVC 3 client side validation on textbox list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

If I allow the user to add text boxes to a view how can I still have my model validation work correctly? I want to be able to send back an array of FanId's to check (which I have done successfully). The problem is that remote validation on each text box sends back the value of the first text box.

Model:

```
[DisplayName("User ID")]
[Remote("ValidateUser","Template",ErrorMessage = "Invalid User Id")]
public string[] FanId { get; set; }
```

Currently I am hard coding the inputs to be added.